# Magento - Facebook Like box only shows up in Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, magento, safari, facebook-likebox

Recently I added the 'Facebook Like Plugin' to my website. However, the Facebook plugin only shows up in chrome:

Chrome: [facebook iframe in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XN0a.jpg)

Safari/IE/Firefox: [facebook iframe in ie/firefox/safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHlRW.png)

I have searched for ages now, and I already tried changing http:// to https:// and to // only.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/*mysite*/?fref=ts" data-width="300" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" margin-bottom="5em;"></div>

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the plugin code and how it fits in your website? Snippets help a lot.

Comment: @mech I am just using the facebook developer like button. Editted the post, thank you

Comment: what does the browser console say?

Comment: @luschn In chrome nothing, in safari: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 

https://*site*/js/venustheme/ves_tempcp/jquery/jquery.min.map

Comment: ok, the sourcemap is not that important...

Comment: btw, you should always use // (without http/https). and make sure that you run this from an actual webserver, of course.

Comment: Where in Magento do you add the plugin, do you add it directly in the source code or via admin (like a static block)?

Comment: @NatalieHedström The facebook import: in 'add-this plugin' custom button box and the javascript in the admin panel. Theres another facebook like box plugin on my website which was added in a static block. However, the same problem happens when loading the page in safari/ie/firefox

Comment: Ah, okay. I was wondering because when adding a `DIV` in a static block, and that div has no content Magento removes it. So you would have to add some content to the Facbook div. e.g `<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/*mysite*/?fref=ts" data-width="300" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" margin-bottom="5em;">&nbsp;</div>`

Comment: @NatalieHedström I have put an image in my post of the admin panel. I think I added the div right?